# Connect to sshd over direct link to second NIC

Tags: networking, ssh, nic

This is how things are by default. I did not set anything up.
My `debian` server has a network connection on `eno2` with ip `192.168.1.40`. Internet, sshd, Everything works fine.

Now I've added a second connection to `eno4`. It's a direct link (no router or switch) to another computer for management purposes. Let's call this one client. On the client, this automatically showed up as `10.0.0.2`. I can ping from the client.

On the server, there was no ip address assigned. But I could netcat from the client just fine, because I only needed the client ip address.

E.g.:

Client:

```
$ echo "Some big ZFS pool here" | nc -l -p 5555
```

Server:

```
$ nc -w 10 10.0.0.2 5555 | cat
Some big ZFS pool here
```

#### Now I want to connect to sshd on the server using this connection.

However, connection is refused. I can connect via LAN and internet over the default `eno2` `192.168.1.40` connection just fine. Just not over this direct link.

By default `sshd` listens to all incoming connections on all interfaces. Perhaps `eno4` just needs an IPv4 address. So I did:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/8 dev eno4
$ ip addr show eno4
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:a5:6a:1b:a2:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/8 scope global eno4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can ping `10.0.0.1` from the server. I can netcat. However, I can not ssh.

There are a lot of long long reads with a *lot* of work addressing all kinds of routing tables and stuff on the web. But I really don't know anything about routing, it's necessity, alternatives, and I'd probably spend the entire day trying it out. But is it really that complex? I can ping. I can netcat. **What is the absolute simplest way to get `ssh` to work on interface?** Might even be temporary, so I can get stuff done *now*?

And, optionally, what is a better permanent solution?

Note that `sshd` is already supposedly listening to everything, and I don't want it to stop listening. I'd prefer not to change the sshd configuration or even restarting sshd, because the server is in active use.

The only thing initially changed on this server is the port:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

Port 22222
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

... snip ...
```

Comment: Does the server have a firewall on it?

Comment: @SimonGreenwood yes but no, `ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere`

Comment: Hmm, IP level security in `sshd_config`?
What sort of output does `ssh -v` give you on the connected machine?

Comment: @SimonGreenwood not as far as I know. `-v` shows a simple `debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.2 port 22222: Connection refused`

Comment: Dumb question, but did you restart ssh since adding the eno4 ip address?

Comment: I don't want to restart ssh on purpose because it shouldn't be necessary. However, I did something dumb nontheless. I wrote my mistake in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparenly, after adding the ip address, **it does work**. I made a mistake in `ssh_config` where I assumed later entries overruled earlier entries, but it's the other way around!

Simplified example; this **does not** work:

```
Host SomeServer
    Hostname 192.168.1.40
    User admin
    Port 22222
Host SomeServer
    # Some temporary overwrite parameters
    Hostname 10.0.0.1
```

However, this **does** work:

```
Host SomeServer
    # Some temporary overwrite parameters
    Hostname 10.0.0.1
Host SomeServer
    Hostname 192.168.1.40
    User admin
    Port 22222
```

I feel a bit silly, and am not sure how I should handle this case:

1. Vote to delete my question
2. Update my question and explain that it actually does work as expected
3. Answer my own question with this clarification

I chose the latter so I can close the case, and apologize for asking an unsolvable question (because actually it already worked).